# Why Dask compute faster the dataframes using from_pandas, than reading directly with dask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

i Have run the same dataset in dask, in differents ways. and I found that one way is almost 10 times fastest than other!!! I try to find the reason without succes.

### 1. Entirely with dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

#Count the number of cores
cores = cpu_count()

#read and part the dataframes by the number of cores
english = dd.read_csv('/home/alberto/Escritorio/pycharm/NLP/ignore_files/es-en/europarl-v7.es-en.en',
               sep='\r', header=None, names=['ingles'], dtype={'ingles':str})
english = english.repartition(npartitions=cores)
spanish = dd.read_csv('/home/alberto/Escritorio/pycharm/NLP/ignore_files/es-en/europarl-v7.es-en.es',
              sep='\r', header=None, names=['espanol'], dtype={'espanol':str})
spanish = english.repartition(npartitions=cores)

#compute
%time total_dd = dd.merge(english, spanish, left_index=True, right_index=True).compute()

Out: 9.77 seg
```

### 2. Pandas + Dask

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

#Count the number of cores
cores = cpu_count()

#Read the Dataframe and part by the number of cores
pd_english = pd.read_csv('/home/alberto/Escritorio/pycharm/NLP/ignore_files/es-en/europarl-v7.es-en.en',
                      sep='\r', header=None, names=['ingles'])

pd_spanish = pd.read_csv('/home/alberto/Escritorio/pycharm/NLP/ignore_files/es-en/europarl-v7.es-en.es',
                      sep='\r', header=None, names=['espanol'])
english_pd = dd.from_pandas(pd_english, npartitions=cores)
spanish_pd = dd.from_pandas(pd_spanish, npartitions=cores)

#compute
%time total_pd = dd.merge(english_pd, spanish_pd, left_index=True, right_index=True).compute()

Out: 1.31 seg
```

Someone knows why? is there other way to do it even faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- *dd.read_csv(...)* does not actually read anything. It is only
  a step of construction of the computation tree.
- as late as when you run *compute*, the **whole** computing tree constructed
  so far is actually executed, **including reading** of both DataFrames.

So in the first variant the timed operation includes:

- reading both DataFrames,
- repartitioning them,
- and finally the *merge* itself.

In the second variant, as far as what is timed, the situation is different.
Both DataFrames have already been read before, so the timed operation
includes only *repartition* and *merge*.

Apparently the source DataFrames are big and reading them takes
considerable time, not accounted for in the second variant.

Try another test: Create a function which:

- reads both DataFrames *pd.read_csv(...)*
- performs the remaining steps (*repartition* and *merge*).

Then compute the execution time of this function.

I suppose, the execution time may be even **longer** than in the
first variant, because:

- in the first variant both DataFrames are read **concurrently**
  (by different cores),
- in the test proposed above the are read **sequentially**.

Comment: Yes, you have reason, thank you. About the Pandas merge I'm really surprised because the merge operation is only **463ms** is the fastest solution for a merge almost 2M rows. I think it's because i merging by the index...